# Is there a way to disable gsp caching for non dev environment

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm looking for a config setting that will tell Grails 2.1 not to cache in a custom environment.  This isn't needed in Dev, but if you specify a custom environment, it would seem that Grails treats it like Prod and caches GSPs.  Other than writing a custom servlet, does anyone have a solution for this?  Is there a config setting that I can set in Config.groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this plugin (I didn't test it yet, but sounds like something you could need):
http://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers

And there is a setting for Config.groovy:

```
grails.gsp.enable.reload=true
```

This is bad for performance, so don't use it in production environment!

Comment: You rock!  Thanks.... This isn't for prod, just a custom env we're developing in. FYI, this isn't cache-header related. It appears that Grails caches on the server as well. Clearing the cache on the browser didn't fix this.